# error while building fovis_ros

Tags: ros, visual-odometry, catkin-package, fovis-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi tried to build package from this source. [git https://github.com/srv/fovis.git] I have successfully built libfovis library. But after this i am getting the following error.

"A lot of code" followed by

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/bhargav/catkin_ws/devel/lib/fovis_ros/fovis_stereo_odometer] Error 1
make[1]: *** [fovis/fovis_ros/CMakeFiles/fovis_stereo_odometer.dir/all] Error 2
```

Please help me build this package successfully.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197006/error-while-building-fovis_ros/) by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-11-10**:
Hi Bhargav,

only with those lines makes it impossible to tell. Could you please paste the full output somewhere and give us the link? For example at https://gist.github.com/

**Comment by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on 2014-11-10**:
@Miquel thank you! i have posted the error here https://gist.github.com/bhargavjha/b0a150457c34f26373aa. Also i was not aware of gist. Thanks for it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the issue is related to our ros node, I'll follow the discussion at https://github.com/srv/fovis/issues/11.
Please, refer to the github issue for more information.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on 2014-11-11**:
thanks a lot! oit worked! :)